# Can I put a view into CTabFolder SWT?

Tags: java, swt

As the title, I want to know that is there any way to put a view that extend ViewPart into a CtabFolder?

I have did some google search but there is nothing can help. So I decided to bring my question to here.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't do this. What is it you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Just show the ViewPart in a CTabFolder as a CTabItem.

Comment: This can't be done but if you explain what you want to achieve there may be another way. You only have this tagged as SWT - ViewPart is not SWT, it is part of the Eclipse plugin architecture - so are you actually writing an Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 0):

After tried more research I have found how to show a ViewPart in a CTabFolder as CTabItem. Here is it:

```
            // create a container for the View part with tabFolder as a parent CTabFolder
            Composite composite = new Composite(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
            composite.setLayout(new FillLayout());

            CTabItem item = null;

            item = new CTabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);

            // Create the one of the ViewPart I want to show in my CTabFolder
            ProjectVersionDriversView myTestViewer = new ProjectVersionDriversView();

            // call the init method on the ViewPart with the current ViewSite
            try {
                myTestViewer.init(this.getViewSite());
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Build the ViewPart within our composite container.
            myTestViewer.createPartControl(composite);
            item.setText("Your Title");
            // set the composite containing the view part as the control for tabItem2.
            item.setControl(composite);
```

It's from [here](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t116797.html).